# Confidence Interval for Exponential

Tags: confidence-interval, python, central-limit-theorem

I am simulating exponentially distributed data with rate $5$ and I want to construct the confidence interval for usual convention $\alpha = 0.05$.

```
from datascience import *
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
plots.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

Arrival = np.random.exponential(5,1000)
Arrival = Table().with_column('Arrival',Arrival)
Arrival.hist()

T_hat = np.mean(Arrival.column(0))
T_hat

(1 + 1.96/np.sqrt(1000))*1/T_hat
(1 - 1.96/np.sqrt(1000))*1/T_hat
```

Here I use the fact that asymptotically, by CLT, $T^h = \sum_{i=1}^nT_i/n$, $T_i$ ~ $Exp(5), i.i.d.$

$\sqrt{n}(T^h - 1/\lambda) ->N(0,1/\lambda^2)$

$\sqrt{n}(\lambda T^h - 1) ->N(0,1) $

Thus, $(1+q_{\alpha/2}/\sqrt{n})1/T^h \le \lambda \le (1+q_{\alpha/2}/\sqrt{n})1/T^h$

The problem is that it seems to me that while the simulation I receive not bound not for $\lambda$ but for $1/\lambda$, in this case $0.21$ and $0.18$

Comment: It sounds like you may have a disagreement with `np.random.exponential`.  Have you consulted its help page to check what its arguments mean?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155805/confidence-interval-for-exponential-distribution